# Finding derivative and integral of $\log(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, logarithms

I'm not very experienced in calculus, so I may have made a mistake somewhere, but I'm confused on how differentiating $\log(x)$ works. I read that $\int \log(x)dx = x(\log(x)) - x + C$, but that leads to some sort of contradiction when you consider that $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} \log(x) = \frac{1}{x\ln(10)}$:
$$\int \log(x) dx = x(\log(x)) - x + C$$
$$ \log(x) = x'\log(x) + \log(x)'x - 1 $$
$$ \log(x) = \log(x) + \log(x)'x - 1 $$
$$ \log(x)'x = 1 $$
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} \log(x) = \frac{1}{x} $$
$$ \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{x\ln(10)} $$
$$ 1 = \ln(10) $$
$$ e = 10 $$

Which is obviously incorrect? What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Edit: Should be written as $\ln(x)/\ln(10)$ instead of $\log(x)$ to avoid confusion.

Comment: Only use natural log ($\ln$), not base 10. Then your problems go away.

Comment: First line: $\int \log x d x=x \log x-x+C$ should be $\quad \int \ln x d x=x \ln x-x+C$

Comment: Generally when things like Wolfram Alpha or a lot of mathematicians write $\log(x)$, they mean $\log_e(x)$ or $\ln(x)$. $\log(x)$ is somewhat ambiguous in general, with base implied to be whatever is most common for your field. Computer science has $\log(x) = \log_2(x)$, for instance; some financial things seem to prefer $\log(x) = \log_{10}(x)$ (and that was how it was taught to me in grade school); etc.

Comment: Oh you're right, I realized I should have written log(x) as ln(x)/ln(10) and that seems to work because if you differentiate that you get $\frac{1}{xln(10)}$, thanks!

Comment: In addition to what has already been said, I would like to quote E.M. Wright, unless it is G. H. Hardy: "log x is, of course, the "Naperian' logarithm of x, to base e. 'Common ' logarithms have no mathematical interest."(*The theory of numbers*)